# Show rows with value greater than 0 then show rows that equal 0

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-order-by

This is my query

```
$offers_with_limit = $db->query("
SELECT *
FROM `offers`
WHERE `countries` LIKE '%'?'%'
  AND `category` = '$query2'
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM completed
     WHERE completed.offer_id = offers.id
       AND completed.user = ?)
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM pending
     WHERE pending.offer_id = offers.id
       AND pending.user = ?)
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM ignored
     WHERE ignored.offer_id = offers.id
       AND ignored.user = ?)
  AND `active` = '1'
  AND `hard_incent` > '0'
ORDER BY `hard_incent` ASC,
         `date_added` DESC LIMIT $startpoint,$limit
    ");
```

Obviously it is only going to show the rows that are greater than 0 but I also need it to continue to show the rows that are equal to 0 after the rows that are greater than if I don't add the `hard_incent > '0'` then it shows the rows that are equal to 0 first because they are in `ASC` order.

Comment: Obviously this will also trigger three dependent subqueries what need three/four full table scans an filesort and temporary table if you run this query with an explain...  Obviously we also need the table structure and some example data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ORDER BY hard_incent <= 0, hard_incent ASC, date_added DESC
```

The first comparison will be 0 for rows that are greater than 0, 1 for rows that are less than or equal to 0, so it will show the greater rows first. Then within those two sets it will order by `hard_incent` and `date_added`.